# how to structure columns in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, powershell, microsoft-excel-2016

I have the following data in excel:

[image]

How can I separate the data into columns? and adding a ";" at the end of each column.

expected output

[image]

I already tried in a thousand ways but I'm lost. I think that putting the correct data type separating numbers from letters but I don't know how to do it, can someone help me?

UPDATE: When trying the code response it does not work since the short names put the timestamp that is the problem at the beginning, I have a csv with only one column with that data but some names do not have 2 surnames they are separated by 1, 2 or 3 spaces depending Of the name, Regarding the modules, I cannot execute any external module in the company.

[image]

Comment: Do I understand that you want **only** PowerShell solutions?  Please edit your question to show the powershell code you have tried.

Comment: Excel is not a text file, it is a package, thus Get-Content is not what you should be using, since that is only for a text file. Excel must either be read via PowerShell using the Excel COM, or you install the Impot-Excel module and use that to manipulate the file. There are many examples right here on SU and all over the web, and on Youtube showing you how to use PowerShell with MSOffice documents. [What did you search for?](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27powershell+Excel+COM%27&t=h_&ia=web) In MSExcel directly, you use the convert-to-column features in the data tab.

Comment: Again in PS, use the Import-Excel module ```Find-Module -Name '*excel*'``` and manipulate the columns as needed. Also, do not post pictures, always post using raw text, or if you do feel you need to post pictures, still post raw text.

Comment: @zeros , if you are using Higher version like 365 ,,, you may use TEXTAFTER ,, TEXTBEFOR or TextSplit ,,, otherwise use Left ,,, Mid & Right with Delimiter used ,,, for eg.  `=LEFT(X1, SEARCH(" ",X1,1)-1)` return OLONSO from B1 ☺

Comment: You can do this easily using VBA and/or Power Query. But you don't respond to questions in the comments, and you don't show what you have tried, so it is difficult to advise you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, this looks like a timeclock app that produced this.

If the was a true single-column text file. You'd just manipulate the string as you read it. For example:

```
# Single column
Clear-Host
'ES123456789 Some Name Some 03/01/2002 00:00:00 00:00:00 00:00:00' | 
ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ' ' -Header h0, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, h7 | 
# Results
<#
h0 : ES123456789
h1 : Some
h2 : Name
h3 : Some
h4 : 03/01/2002
h5 : 00:00:00
h6 : 00:00:00
h7 : 00:00:00
#>
Select-Object -Property @{
    Name       = 'Key'
    Expression = {$PSitem.h0 + ';'}
},
@{
    Name       = 'FullName'
    Expression = {$PSitem.h1 + ' ' + $PSItem.h2 + ' ' + $PSItem.h3 + ';'}
},
@{
    Name       = 'Timestamp'
    Expression = {$PSitem.h4 + ' ' + $PSItem.h5 + ' ' + $PSItem.h6 + $PSItem.h7 +';'}
}
# Results
<#
Key          FullName        Timestamp                            
---          --------        ---------                            
ES123456789; Some Name Some; 03/01/2002 00:00:00 00:00:0000:00:00;
#>
```

The above just split the string on a space and uses calculated properties to join back how you want.

If it were two or more columns, you could simply join them first, then take the same approach, enclose the two as one and parse.
For example:

```
# Two columns
Clear-Host
"
'ES123456789 Some Name', 'Some 03/01/2002 00:00:00 00:00:00 00:00:00'
'ES123456780 Another Name', 'Another 03/01/2002 00:00:00 00:00:00 00:00:00'
" | 
ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ',' -Header h0, h1 | 
# Results
<#
h0                         h1                                             
--                         --                                             
'ES123456789 Some Name'    'Some 03/01/2002 00:00:00 00:00:00 00:00:00'   
'ES123456780 Another Name' 'ANother 03/01/2002 00:00:00 00:00:00 00:00:00'
#>
ForEach-Object {
    $RecodObjects = [PSCustomObject]@{
        Key       = ($PSItem.h0 -split ' ',2)[0] + ';' -replace "'" 
        Fullname  = ($PSItem.h0 -split ' ',2)[1] + ' ' + ($PSItem.h1 -split ' ',2)[0] + ';' -replace "'" 
        TimeStamp = ($PSItem.h1 -split ' ',2)[1] + ';' -replace "'" 
    }
    $RecodObjects 
}
# Results
<#
Key          Fullname              TimeStamp                             
---          --------              ---------                             
ES123456789; Some Name Some;       03/01/2002 00:00:00 00:00:00 00:00:00;
ES123456780; Another Name Another; 03/01/2002 00:00:00 00:00:00 00:00:00;
#>
```

You'd do the same thing in Excel COM,...

> https://lazywinadmin.com/2014/03/powershell-read-excel-file-using-com.html

...or in Excel directly, by using the Excel features, ***Text to columns*** option in the data tab menu.

[Just search for Excel text to columns and Excel text split and or join, for examples.](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27Excel%20text%20split%20%20and%20join%27&t=h_&ia=web)

All you'll end up doing is creating a new column in the spreadsheet, and creating a formula to read the other two columns and join the results, thus using that new column for whatever you want.

['Excel join data from two columns'](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27Excel%20join%20data%20from%20two%20columns%27&t=h_&ia=web)

Thus ending up with Excel cell formulas like this.

```
ColumnA: ES123456789 Some Name
ColumnB: Some 03/01/2002 00:00:00 00:00:00 00:00:00
ColumnC: =CONCATENATE(LEFT(A1,SEARCH(" ",A1)),";")
ColumnD: =CONCATENATE(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-SEARCH(" ",A1,1))," ",LEFT(B1,SEARCH(" ",B1)),";")
ColumnE: =CONCATENATE(RIGHT(B1,LEN(B1)-SEARCH(" ",B1,3)),";")
```

You can do the above via PS as well using the tools previously mentioned. For Example:

```
$FilePath         = 'D:\Temp\how to structure columns in excel.xlsx'
$objExcel         = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$objExcel.Visible = $true
$WorkBook         = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open($FilePath)

<#
$WorkBook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Value2
$WorkBook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.EntireRow.Value2
#>
# Results
<#
ES123456789 Some Name
Some 03/01/2002 00:00:00 00:00:00 00:00:00
ES123456780 Another Name
Another 03/01/2002 00:00:00 00:00:00 00:00:00
#>


$SheetData = $WorkBook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows | 
ForEach-Object {
    $PSItem.Value2 -join ',' | 
    ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ',' -Header Key, TimeStamp
}
# Results
<#
Key                      TimeStamp                                    
---                      ---------                                    
ES123456789 Some Name    Some 03/01/2002 00:00:00 00:00:00 00:00:00   
ES123456780 Another Name Another 03/01/2002 00:00:00 00:00:00 00:00:00
#>

$ReportWorksheet      = $WorkBook.Worksheets.Add()
$ReportWorksheet.Name = "Timesheet Report"
$RowCounter           = 0

$SheetData | 
ForEach-Object {
    $RowCounter += 1

    $ReportData = [PSCustomObject]@{
        Key       = ($PSItem.Key -split ' ',2)[0] + ';' -replace "'" 
        FullName  = ($PSItem.Key -split ' ',2)[1] + ' ' + ($PSItem.TimeStamp -split ' ',2)[0] + ';' -replace "'" 
        TimeStamp = ($PSItem.TimeStamp -split ' ',2)[1] + ';' -replace "'" 
    }

    $ReportWorksheet.Cells.Item($RowCounter,1) = $ReportData.Key
    $ReportWorksheet.Cells.Item($RowCounter,2) = $ReportData.FullName
    $ReportWorksheet.Cells.Item($RowCounter,3) = $ReportData.TimeStamp
}
# Results
<#
Key          FullName        TimeStamp                             
---          --------        ---------                             
ES123456789; Some Name Some; 03/01/2002 00:00:00 00:00:00 00:00:00;
ES123456789; Some Name Some; 03/01/2002 00:00:00 00:00:00 00:00:00;
#>

$ReportWorksheet.UsedRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit()

$WorkBook.SaveAs( "D:\Temp\TimeSheetReport.xlsx")
$WorkBook.Save = $true
```

[image]

Yet, if you are doing that as a one-off, then scripting this is unnecessary.

[image]

***Update as per my last comment to you***
Again, you can do this directly in MS Excel, with Excel formulas if this is not a regular thing. Scripting a one-off is really overthinking this.

```
# Single column RegEx capture for data refactor
Clear-Host
$FilePath         = 'D:\Temp\how to structure columns in excel.xlsx'
$objExcel         = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$objExcel.Visible = $true
$WorkBook         = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open($FilePath)

$ReportData = $WorkBook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Value2 | 
ForEach-Object {
    ([RegEx]::Matches($PSItem, 'ES\d{9}').Value).Trim() + 
    ';,' + (([RegEx]::Matches($PSItem, "(?<=ES\d{9})(.*\s)(?=\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,4}.*)").Value) -replace "\s+", ' ').Trim() + 
    ';,' + ([RegEx]::Matches($PSItem, "\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,4}.*").Value).Trim() + ';'
}

$ReportWorksheet      = $WorkBook.Worksheets.Add()
$ReportWorksheet.Name = "Timesheet Report"
$RowCounter           = 0

$ReportData | 
ForEach-Object {
    $RowCounter += 1

    $ReportWorksheet.Cells.Item(($RowCounter), 1) = ($PSItem -split ',')[0]
    $ReportWorksheet.Cells.Item(($RowCounter), 2) = ($PSItem -split ',')[1]
    $ReportWorksheet.Cells.Item(($RowCounter), 3) = ($PSItem -split ',')[2]
}

[void]$ReportWorksheet.UsedRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit()

Remove-Item -Path 'D:\Temp\TimeSheetReport.xlsx' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force
$WorkBook.SaveAs( "D:\Temp\TimeSheetReport.xlsx", 51)
[void]$WorkBook.Save
```

[image]

Comment: answer above and edit question

Comment: @zeros. Your changes are not what you originally posted. Your original post was 2 columns. What I provide is still prudent, and you need to change it from looking at multiple columns to one and account for the spaces as you need to. You could also avoid the whole Excel COM stuff, by saving that XLS as a true CSV, and treating that as normal text via ```Get-Content```, then opening that in Excel or whatever as needed. Split by space and reassemble as needed as my first solution showed. ***Again, no posting pictures, without a plain text version.*** No one wants to retype stuff.

Comment: @zeros. One more item as to the 3rdP stuff. Know that the moment you move to Microsoft Powershell Core (PowerShellv7 and beyond pwsh.exe), it is all open-sourced, So, all is MS and 3rdP contributes and maintain it all.

Comment: The problem is that the file has a million records and your code is not dealing with the problem of the name since each of those million records is different.

Comment: Since none of us would have your data and thus be able to determine all differences in the strings, all we can do is give you starting pointer to get you started. Based on what you say, you first need to determine all those variances, and code for them explicitly, RegEx stuff. You are obviously dealing with a very unstructured file, and you need to code to structure it. Again, RegEx stuff.

Comment: Can you give me an example with code with a single column and entering a simple regex

Comment: The RgeEx for the most part can just be 3 parts, just like the properties I show in the code. The 1st RegEx pulls the key, the 2nd RegEx is to pull the strings between the key and the timestamp string, and of course the 3rd RegEx is to pull the datetimehour string. Lastly, format as needed. See my update for you. The RegEx is not simple, btw. It's granular per string segment. YOu can practice with it via https://regex101.com, if you have not spent much time toying with RegEx parsing.

Comment: Could you give me an example if the file was a csv?